# Can I distribute apps purchased through VPP program outside the company?

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an app that would fit in well with Apple's B2B program. The only problem is that the end-users are at small companies which don't have much technical know-how. As it stands, each of our customers would have to take the following steps:

1. Register for the VPP program.
2. Buy our "free" app for each of their users.
3. Distribute the download links/codes to each user.

To make the experience go more smoothly, we'd like to basically cut them out of the process. Is it allowed by Apple for us to use our own VPP account to purchase apps on behalf of the client? The process would then look like this:

1. We register for the VPP program.
2. We buy our "free" app for all customers and their users.
3. Our users login to our web backend and have a link already associated to their account to install the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like this is off-topic as it deals with licensing, not programming.

Comment: We are basically in the same situation. Any new information about a viable approach?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of days back I spoke to someone from the Apple Developer Relations Team and we also discussed this exact case. Unfortunately the VPP is intended to distribute apps only to members of your organization, such as employees. This excludes partners, resellers, candidates, etc. When it comes to that, it seems to follow the same rules as the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).

Having said that, it would not be allowed that a developer or agency distributes the app via VPP to employees of another or even multiple companies. It is intended that the company of the target user hosts the VPP program themselves. Your customers therefore have to create the VPP program and manage the distribution themselves. Of course, they could invite you to the program as an administrator after creating it in order to optimize that process.

Only exception would be if there is one specific agency exclusively catering the app to one company. However they would only be allowed to do that for that one specific customer in a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Is that agency can be the one that develops the app?
What I mean is that we would create 1 email for each company and we would register with that, and the current company's name and duns number.

Comment: @Xyzor So you are basically one agency that sets up and maintains the VPP program for multiple customers who want to distribute apps to their employees? Yes that should work as long as the ownership is with your customers, you are just maintaining the VPP program. I assume it would be safer if they create it and invite you afterwards.